# Default values are not rendering on Wishlist product edit page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, configurable-product, wishlist, configurable-product-options

Default values are not rendering on wishlist product edit page

**Steps to generate the issue:**

1. Navigate to any configurable product page on the frontend.
2. Select the dropdown options and add the product to wishlist.
3. Navigate to My Wishlist page.
4. Click on Edit link given in wishlist item.

[image]

**Expected Result:**

It should auto-select the dropdown options on wishlist product edit page.

[image]

**Actual Result:**

It doesn't auto-select the dropdown options.

[image]

> Additional note: When I flush the cache and then click on Edit link,
>   it auto-select the options.

I have checked it in Magento 2.2.2 and 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for fix Auto-select the dropdown options on wishlist product edit page.

**Rewrite options-updater.js file and add below fix.**

**File path:**

magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/options-updater.js

**Find below line from options-updater.js**

$(selectors.formSelector).on(this.eventName, function () {

and add **this.updateOptions();** after complete that funtion.

**Before fix issue:**

```
$(selectors.formSelector).on(this.eventName, function () {
    this.setProductOptions(cartData());
    this.updateOptions();
}.bind(this));
```

**After fix issue:**

```
$(selectors.formSelector).on(this.eventName, function () {
    this.setProductOptions(cartData());
    this.updateOptions();
}.bind(this));
this.updateOptions();
```

Hope it help!

Let me know if any issue.